# How do I print the first page of a Windows Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm new to C# and created a Windows Forms application with a web browser control.  I'm able to programatically print out the form, but it's printing multiple pages.

I tried disabling the scroll bars but that didn't work.  Is there a way to only set the parameters so it only prints the first page without having to call the print dialogue box?

**Edit**: I was able to disable the scroll bars and I tried adjusting the printer settings but it's still printing out every page.

Thanks